# Hadoop 2.x line: How "Alpha" is "alpha"

Tags: architecture, hadoop

From the release page on hadoop’s website:

> “This release, like previous releases in hadoop-2.x series is still
>   considered alpha primarily since some of APIs aren't fully-baked and
>   we expect some churn in future.”

How “alpha” is the 2.x line? We’re moving off AWS (1.0.3) onto our own cluster of 10 servers, naturally we want the latest and greatest, but don’t need to live on the bleeding edge (we just wanna process some data, you know!).

So how “Alpha” is “alpha”?

Comment: Even in hadoop 0.20 there were some APIs that were deprecated and then un-deprecated again because their replacements were not well supported. I have a strong hunch that sticking with the latest 1.x stable is the right choice.

Comment: This is a great comment, and good food for thought, but I'm less concerned with re-factoring code than I am with general stability.

Comment: 2.x runs on 2k servers already. It is just flagged alpha because it doesn't run on 10k ;-)

Comment: @ThomasJungblut That's not entirely true. There are notable problems with the alpha releases, they may even be listed. For one, don't remember the exact release, but one of the previous alphas refused to run HBase on a normal configuration. Moving it back to 1.0.4 resolved all problems. Basically, YMMV. Test it, if everything runs, use it. Otherwise don't.

Comment: @TC1 as far as I know the TE didn't talk about HBase, these are integration issues that are hopefully resolved with BigTop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that YARN is new and a radical change so you you'd probably want to be more careful with using that. Most other changes are incremental. You can use a distro like Claudera's CDH4 which support Hadoop 1.x map-reduce on Hadoop 2.x